# PYTHON change part of Column names (date)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about change multiple column names.

here is my column information:

```
print(df.columns)

Index([           'ID',          'AREA', 2020-04-11 00:00:00,
       2020-04-12 00:00:00, 2020-04-13 00:00:00, 2020-04-14 00:00:00,
       2020-04-15 00:00:00, 2020-04-16 00:00:00, 2020-04-17 00:00:00,
       2020-04-18 00:00:00,
       ...
       2021-05-30 00:00:00, 2021-05-31 00:00:00, 2021-06-01 00:00:00,
       2021-06-02 00:00:00, 2021-06-03 00:00:00, 2021-06-04 00:00:00,
       2021-06-05 00:00:00, 2021-06-06 00:00:00, 2021-06-07 00:00:00,
       2021-06-08 00:00:00],
      dtype='object', length=426)
```

The output should be:

```
id area 04/12/2020 04/13/2020......06/08/2021
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot,

JH

Comment: Perhaps look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: Thanks. My file has 426 columns, where 424 columns need to rename. Do you mean the only way to do that is I need to rename it one by one 424 times?

Comment: hi @JeanHu! I tried to write an answer as far as I understood. Can you please provide feedback whether it worked or not so that it can be improved dependingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ Mustafa Aydın, t works very well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two are manual, others with `pd.to_datetime` and `DatetimeIndex.format`:

```
df.columns = ["id", "area", *pd.to_datetime(df.columns[2:]).format(date_format="%m/%d/%Y")]
```

to get

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['id', 'area', '04/11/2020', '04/12/2020', '04/13/2020', '04/14/2020', ...], dtype='object')
```

---

or explicitly separating, perhaps more readable:

```
first_two = ["id", "area"]
others = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[2:]).format(date_format="%m/%d/%Y")

df.columns = first_two + others
```

gives the same result.